# "Cannot install Nagios::Plugin, don't know what it is."

Tags: perl, nagios, cpan

I used this command to install Nagios::Plugins on multiple servers months/weeks before:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Nagios::Plugin'
```

Now I get this error message:

```
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Mon, 27 Apr 2015 00:29:02 GMT
Warning: Cannot install Nagios::Plugin, don't know what it is.
```

As far as I can tell, the module is still in CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Nagios-Plugin/

What´s wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nagios::Plugins` was [renamed](https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugin-perl/commit/b418181dfe80dd75169b6e8a619ac1932155dea2) to `Monitoring::Plugins` due to trademark reason. `cpan` doesn't index `Nagios::Plugins` anymore. Now you must install `Monitoring::Plugin`

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Monitoring::Plugin'
```

Or you can install it via cpanm. First install cpanm:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

and then install the module

```
cpanm Monitoring::Plugin
```

**Further reading**

- https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=102080
- https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/news/new-project-name.html